# JSON Decoder returning No value associated with key CodingKeys e.g "expires_date" in IAP receipt

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm implemented `Auto-Renewable subscriptions` about 2 months ago and they were working fine.

However, when I came back to test them in the sandbox now, I've ended up getting `No value with key expires_date found`.

I debugged and printed out the `latest_receipt_info` and it is clearly a string. Why is this happening? I've looked at the receipt again and Apple changed some the keys to `Int` but my `expires` date still remains the same. Where am I going wrong?

Here is my code and the receipt. The error says

> > "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"expires_date\", intValue: nil) (\"expires_date\")."

Latest Receipt

```
"latest_receipt_info" =     (
                {
            "expires_date" = "2019-02-06 15:50:21 Etc/GMT";
            "expires_date_ms" = 1549468221000;
            "expires_date_pst" = "2019-02-06 07:50:21 America/Los_Angeles";
            "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2019-03-21 08:37:40 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1553157460000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2019-03-21 01:37:40 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000495291060;
            "product_id" = "com.myApp.myApp.autoRenewableSubscription";
            "purchase_date" = "2019-02-06 15:45:21 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1549467921000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2019-02-06 07:45:21 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000512208509;
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000042609485;
        }
```

Receipt info

```
struct IAPReceiptInfo: Decodable {

    let expiresDate: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
    }
}

struct IAPReceipt: Decodable {

    let latestReceipt: String
    let status: Int
    var receiptInfo = [IAPReceiptInfo]()

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Codingkeys.self)
        self.latestReceipt = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .latestReceipt)
        self.status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        self.receiptInfo = try container.decode([IAPReceiptInfo].self, forKey: .latestInfos)
    }

    var latestInfo: IAPReceiptInfo? {
        return self.receiptInfo.last
    }

    var IAPLatestReceipt: String {
        return self.latestReceipt
    }

    private enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latestReceipt = "latest_receipt"
        case status
        case latestInfos = "latest_receipt_info"
    }
}
```

IAPReceiptAPI

```
    func sendReceiptForToServer(completion pCompletion: @escaping (([IAPReceiptInfo]?, Error?) -> Void)) {
         let receiptData = self.getReceipt?.base64EncodedString()
         let requestReceiptDict = ["receipt": receiptData]
        if receiptData == nil {
            let error = NSError(domain: "No Rec", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
            pCompletion(nil, error)
        }
        do {
            let data = try requestReceiptDict.vyEncode()
            guard let validationUrl = URL(string: "https://us-central1-myApp-a8e27.cloudfunctions.net/receiptValidation") else { return }
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            var request = URLRequest(url: validationUrl, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = data
            let task = session.uploadTask(with:request, from: data) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    let receipt = try IAPReceipt.vyDecode(data: data)
                    if let receiptLatestInfo = receipt.latestInfo {
                        pCompletion([receiptLatestInfo], nil)
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    pCompletion(nil, error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } catch let error {
            pCompletion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution is:
 let expiresDate: String
 To
let expiresDate: Int

Comment: Its not an `Int`. The `JSON` returned clearly states its a string. How can a `date` be an `Int`?

Comment: According to the above error, I thought date comes as a timestamp. That's the reason I told you to Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that `expires_date` has been changed and might be missing in some cases there by had to make it an `optional` and work now.

```
struct IAPReceiptInfo: Decodable {

    let expiresDate: String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case expiresDate = "expires_date"
    }
}
```